# How many times have major league teams won a championship after winning 4 Game 7s?

Tags: trivia, international-sports, postseason

The LA Kings beat the Chicago Blackhawks in [Game 7 of the Western Conference Finals](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/2014-chicago-blackhawks-vs-los-angeles-kings-western-conference-finals.html) during the Stanley Cup Playoffs on June 1, 2014. The Kings have won Game 7 of all three series to get to the Stanley Cup Finals.

I'm wondering if a team ever went on to win the championship after winning 4 Game 7s? If so, can you provide a list of the team and the year of accomplishment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has never happened. The closest any time has come in Hockey since the NHL moved to four 7 game series has been the [Bruins](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_2011.html) in 2011 and the Kings in 2014. They each won three game 7s. The Bruins in the first, third and fourth rounds. No team has even *played* four game 7s that I could find since the league went to four 7 game series in the 80s. The Kings can make history this year.

I also went ahead and checked basketball (the other major US sport that plays four 7 game series for their playoffs), and no team has played four game 7s in that league either.

Comment: I was gonna say - it's been all over the internet/news that the Kings are the first team ever to win 3 game 7's on the road and only the second team to ever win 3 game 7's. I heard all about this and I'm not even that big of a hockey fan.

Comment: @jamauss yeah, and neither league has played 4 sets of 7 games for long enough for any kind of real history to have been built up (NBA started in early 2ks, NHL in the 80s)